# Use quartz composer for creating time lapse videos

Tags: photo, quartz-composer, timelapse

Hy there let's say I have 1000 pictures which were taken with a delay of 1 second.

1. Is it possible to create a video from these pictures using quartz composer?
2. In a second step I would like to add labels to the video stream depending on the current time of the given picture so that you can see how time flies by while watching the video.
3. In a third step I think it would be very cool to have something like an animated analogue clock that displays the time instead of a label.

   [clock http://www.thepropheticartist.com/images/animated_clock.gif](http://www.thepropheticartist.com/images/animated_clock.gif)
4. There is no fourth step :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, there's currently no way to combine individual pictures into a QuickTime movie using Quartz Composer.  Apple does provide example code for writing individual images to disk, so currently at best you could load an image, process it, and write an image to disk.
2. Use the `System Time`, `Date Formatter`, `Image With String`, and `Billboard` patches.
3. In `/Developer/Library/Quartz Composer/Examples/Patches/`, there's `Clock.qtz`, which renders an analog clock.
4. No comment.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Do you know if it is possible to use the image's capture time instead of the `System Time`?

I currently have created just the movie without any labels on them using Aperture. The good thing there is that I can time the images according to the beats of the background music. So I could process all the images write them to disk and then re-import them in Aperture.

Comment: Using [Kineme FileTools](http://kineme.net/FileTools) you can get the file's creation and modification timestamps.  (I'm not aware of a way to read EXIF tags in QC, though.)